# How to dynamically show the current time (and not date) in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time, cell-format

I want to fill a cell with the current time, so it changes every time I open the file.

I currently use the `NOW()` function for that, but it returns both the date and the time.

I want to see only the time. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you entered the formual =now() to the cell, select the cell and press Ctrl + Shift + 2
You're welcome!

Comment: Note that this only formats the cell as time. The underlying value is still Date and Time

Comment: Just adding on, Just set the type of cell to date or long date or time as needed to play around with different type of values.

Answer (score 21):

try this formula

<s>=NOW()-TRUNC(NOW())</s>

```
=NOW()-TODAY()
```

Comment: Note that TRUNC(NOW()) = TODAY()

Comment: This gives me some kind of digital number, unless I format the cell as date... But I don't want to have to format the cell explicitly. With the now() function, the cell formats without any external intervention...

Comment: In both cases the underlying data is a Date Serial Number.  In the first case Excel is just applying the format for you.  You have no option but to apply a format.

Comment: @Lea_Cohen you could use TEXT function to get the time, e.g. use `=TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm")` - change "hh:mm" part as required - no formatting required (although the cell now contains text rather than a time - not crucial if this is for display)

Comment: @Barry that will do it.  (My guess - next question: how do I use that time in a formula)

Comment: Next Answer! You can just use +0 to convert usually, e.g. if TEXT formula is in A1 then A1+0 converts to a time you can use in another formula/function

Comment: @barryhoudini - it's fine. It still acts as a time - I'm able to subtract another time cell from it

Comment: Yes, as soon as you do a mathematical operation (like subtraction) that `co-erces` the value.....but it wouldn't work in a comparison with another time without using +0, e.g. `=A1>TIME(23,59,59)` - where TEXT function is in A1 - that's always TRUE, need to use `=A1+0>TIME(23,59,59)` to get correct results

Comment: IMO this is the best answer as it is so elegant. It should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
=Now()
```

1. Right Click on `Cell`
2. Click `Format Cells`
3. Click on `Custom` on left side
4. Select the time format as `h:mm:ss AM/PM`
5. Click `OK`

One more Solution:-

```
=TEXT(NOW(), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I do now. What I'm looking for is a way that will save me these 5 steps...

Comment: Why not write a macro that does these 5 steps then?

Comment: @LeaCohen: I have updated my answer with one more solution.

Comment: @Siva_Charan Snap! see my comment...........

Comment: @barryhoudini: Sorry I didn't noticed your comment. Since you have posted 1 min before me, should I remove my answer.

Comment: No worries, same time I'd say.......

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

TIME(VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(NOW(), "HH:MM:SS"), 2)), VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(TEXT(NOW(), "HH:MM:SS"), 5), 2)), VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(NOW(), "SS:MM:SS"), 2)))

This will effectively break up the hours, minutes and seconds returned from the format function and format them as a time. I haven't tried it in the afternoon, so I'm not sure if you get problems with am/pm.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to included the corrected formula

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SECOND(NOW()))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To just show the time you would hold -->   CTRL + :  <-- this will display the time only.

Comment: Hi Admingrl, and welcome to SuperUser. Your answer is great if I want a shortcut for displaying the time one-time-only. But I was looking for a way to display the current time dynamically - that each time I open the spreadsheet, the cell will show the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
=NOW()-TODAY(),
```

If you want to use it in a formula like "end time" - "current time" to find "total hours" then just format the "total hours" cell to number and multiply the whole formula by `24` like this

```
Current Time   Finish Time     Total Hours

=NOW()-TODAY()  8:30 PM         =(B2-B1)*24
```

Answer (score 0):

In time-related calculations you could use [the following formula](https://pakaccountants.com/separate-integer-decimal-part-number-excel/#4_INT_and_MOD_functions):

```
=MOD(NOW(); 1)
```

It returns the same value as @ChrisNeilsen's formula, but using less steps and getting the current date only once. The downside of this formula is the use of division.

- To display this value as time, format a cell as Time or Duration.
- To get the time as a fractional number of hours, multiply this formula by 24.

In Google Sheets you could use the following hack instead:
<sup>(the [`TIMEVALUE()` function expects a string](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en), but it works anyway)</sup>

```
=TIMEVALUE(NOW())
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a link showing how to do this
[CLOCK WITH AUTOMATIC REFRESH](https://sites.google.com/site/excelforbeginners/Home/vba-codes/clock-with-automatic-refresh)

in line **With Sheet1.Range("A1")** replace **Sheet1** with actual sheet name where you want this clock and **A1** with cell where you want your clock

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  If you post an answer that's just a link, it's harder for people to see whether it will be helpful for them, and it can become meaningless if the target website goes offline.  It's better to quote the important information directly, and just give the link for further reading.

Answer (score -3):

There's a built in function for this, to only provide the time.  The function is =Time().  This keeps it from displaying the date, and will only display the current time of the OS upon the creation of a new entry.

Comment: Have you tried this? In what version of Excel does it work like that?